# C# How to send Data from DatagridView to Data Repeater

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarepeater

I have a form with a datagridview and a Data Repeater.
On double click on a row in datagrid view i can pass a value to a textBox1 , but i cannot pass a value to another textbox inside the data repeater here is my code and please check image of form for better information .

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        patient_ID_FKTextBox.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //this is my issue unsuccessfull value pass
        textBox1.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString(); //Name 100% successfull value pass 
    }


private void Table_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'physioDBDataSet1.AssessmentForm' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.assessmentFormTableAdapter.Fill(this.physioDBDataSet1.AssessmentForm);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'physioDBDataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.physioDBDataSet.Table);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'physioDBDataSet.NeckMeasurments' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.neckMeasurmentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.physioDBDataSet.NeckMeasurments);
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you realize you are passing dr.Cells[0] to patient_ID_FKTextBox instead of dr.Cells[1]? Is that your issue?

Comment: yes i this how i suppose to pass it because cell 0 is for ID and cell 1 for Name, but i put it invisible in datagridview

Comment: I was not able to know that because you did not provide enough code.  You also need to post the exception you are actually getting.

Comment: This is the only code i wrote, i used mostly drag and drop to be able to insert into the db plus i am not getting any error to get an exception to show :/

Comment: Are you sure there is actually a value in Cells[0]? If you make it visible and debug the program do you actually see the ID in cell 0? If so, set a breakpoint where you assign it to patient_ID_FKTextBox.Text. After you step over that breakpoint hover your mouse over the "text" part of patient_ID_FKTextBox.Text. What value is being assigned?

Comment: It is being assigned "1" the value of primary key of Mike. (thanks for heads up on break points)